# Elegant method of generating this matrix?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays, expression-construction

Good evening,
I need to determine an elegant (as possible) method of computing an $n\times n$ matrix below (the matrix shown is just a $16\times16$ example). I've been toying with `For` loops, `Table`s, `Band`s, `DiagonalMatrix`, etc. but due to my lack of *Mathematica* knowledge, I'm at a complete loss as to which method would be most computationally efficient.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 6 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 16 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 10 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 24 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 14 & 0 & 28 & 0 & 28 & 0 & 28 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 32 & 0 & 32 & 0 & 32 & 0 & 32 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 18 & 0 & 36 & 0 & 36 & 0 & 36 & 0 & 36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 40 & 0 & 40 & 0 & 40 & 0 & 40 & 0 & 40 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 22 & 0 & 44 & 0 & 44 & 0 & 44 & 0 & 44 & 0 & 44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 48 & 0 & 48 & 0 & 48 & 0 & 48 & 0 & 48 & 0 & 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 26 & 0 & 52 & 0 & 52 & 0 & 52 & 0 & 52 & 0 & 52 & 0 & 52 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 56 & 0 & 56 & 0 & 56 & 0 & 56 & 0 & 56 & 0 & 56 & 0 & 56 & 0 & 0 \\
 30 & 0 & 60 & 0 & 60 & 0 & 60 & 0 & 60 & 0 & 60 & 0 & 60 & 0 & 60 & 0 \\
\end{array}

Comment: I strongly doubt computational efficiency is relevant here.  Even inefficient *Mathematica* code can generate matrices with millions of entries in less than 0.1 second.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, but usually inefficient code produces unpacked arrays and decreases the further performance.

Comment: Three answers and no upvote yet??  (+1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Update:* here `Table` is faster and more user-friendly then `Array`.

```
mat[n_] := LowerTriangularize@Table[2 (1 + Boole[j > 1]) (i - 1) Mod[i + j, 2], 
 {i, n}, {j, n}];

mat[10] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

It is fast and the result is [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496)

```
mat[1000] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.142522, True} *)
```

Comment: This gets the first column wrong.  But it's close!

Comment: It also puts entries on the main diagonal, rather than one below the main diagonal.

Comment: @evanb I made a mistake in indexing. See my update.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

None of the above are particularly "efficient", if that's your goal. By way of example,

```
mat = Module[{p1 = Range[0, 2 # - 2, 2], p2},
    p2 = p1*2;
    p1[[1 ;; ;; 2]] = 0;
    p2[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = 0;
    LowerTriangularize@Transpose[PadRight[{p1}, #, {2 p1, p2}]]] &;

mat[200];//Timing

(*

{0., Null}

*)
```

And that's on an old netbook. Compared to fastest of the answers so far (the rest ranged from slower to unusably slow):

Update: A faster method, dispenses with the most expensive operation of above, ~2x speed,
averaged ~30X faster than fastest answer so far, 72X faster peak, under the range of tests in updated graph (Again, on an old netbook, I'd expect bigger difference w/ more cores...):

[image]

The new method:

```
newmat = Module[{p1 = Range[0, 2 # - 2, 2], p2},
   p2 = p1;
   p1[[1 ;; ;; 2]] = 0;
   p2[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = 0;
   LowerTriangularize@Join[Transpose@{p1}, 
     ArrayPad[Transpose[{2 p2, 2 p1}], {{0, 0}, {0, # - 3}}, "Periodic"], 2]] &;
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my version using [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
mat2[n_]:=SparseArray[{{i_,j_}/;And[i>j,Mod[i+j,2]==1]:> If[j==1,2,4](i-1)},{n,n},0.];
MatrixForm@mat2[10]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this meets the spec:

```
gKirkland[rows_, columns_] := Outer[
  Function[{i, j},
   If[i <= j, 0,
      If[Mod[i + j, 2] == 0, 0, 1] If[j == 1, 1/2, 1] (4 (i - 1))
      ]
  ], Range[1, rows], Range[1, columns]]
```

`gKirkland[16,16]` gives the matrix as shown.  `gKirkland[1000,1000]` evaluates in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
sparse[n_] :=
 Module[{range, column, bands},
  range = Range[8, 4 n - 4, 4];
  column = Table[{i, 1} -> 2 (i - 1), {i, 2, n, 2}];
  bands = Table[Band[{i, 2}] -> Drop[range, (i - 3)], {i, 3, n, 2}];
  SparseArray[column~Join~bands, {n, n}]]
```

Construction of `sparse[1000]` in 0.35 seconds.

## Update

`Drop` in `Band` can be dropped since `Band` stops putting values into places as soon as the edge of a matrix is reached.

```
sparse[n_] :=
 Module[{range, firstColumn, bands},
  range = Range[4 n - 4, 8, -4];
  firstColumn = Table[{i, 1} -> 2 (i - 1), {i, 2, n, 2}];
  bands = Table[Band[{n, n - j},
      Automatic, {-1, -1}] -> range, {j, 1, n - 3, 2}];
  SparseArray[firstColumn~Join~bands, {n, n}]]
```